# Why does using Message.get_payload() give the correct string, while using Message.get_payload(decode=True) gives an incorrect string?

Tags: python, email, imaplib

My code connects to an email inbox, and reads subjects and contents of each email.

My code:

```
def decode_email(self, raw_email):
    msg=email.message_from_string(raw_email.decode('utf-8')) 

    content = ''
    if msg.is_multipart():
        for part in msg.walk(): 
            print('multipart')
            thispart = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                if isinstance(thispart, bytes): 
                    thispart = thispart.decode()
                content = content + thispart
    else:
        content = msg.get_payload(decode=True)  #THIS LINE HAS A PROBLEM
        if isinstance(content, bytes):
            content = content.decode()
```

When multipart, everything seems to go well.

But when singlepart, `content = msg.get_payload(decode=True)` gives a weird result.

> b'\ub0b4\uc6a9\r\n'

And `content = content.decode()` gives

> \ub0b4\uc6a9

which isn't what I expect.

But when I remove the decode option, `content = msg.get_payload()`, the right string comes out.

Why does this happen?

The [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload) seems to say that the string is decoded only when needed.

Any thought appreciated :)

Comment: FIrst, use message_from_bytes, do not try to decode the message yourself.

Comment: @Max What could be a problem when using message_from_string(rawemail.decode()), compared to using message_from_bytes(rawemail)?

Comment: If the raw message is not pure ASCII, you will corrupt it, since you will decode it not knowing what character set to use.